# Multiple output from reducer, banded sum

Tags: apache-spark

So I want to do a sum by buckets for a key. I have a data looking something like:

```
<a> <1, 10>
<a> <2, 12>
<b> <4, 12>
<a> <1, 20>
<a> <3, 21>
```

I want to sum by the key, but also but in a way that I may get sums only for a certain bandwidth of the second term in the tuple. Say if I say my bandwidth is 2 I wish to have this output:

```
<a> <3>
<a> <4>
<b> <4>
```

I was able to do this using reduceByKey by first mapping the values to the list and then iterating and checking lists. However this would require going O(n^2) times for every key where n is the number of values per key.

Just wondering if there is a easier way to do this in spark. Tried doing aggregations, but it boils down to the same thing, I believe.

**UPDATE**

So this is what I did.

1. Map each value as a list to get something like:

> ```
> <a> <[1,10]>
> <a> <[2,12]>
> <b> <[4,12]>
> <a> <[1,20]>
> <a> <[3,21]>
> ```

2. Call `reduceByKey`, this for two entries say `<a> <[1,10]>` and `<a> <a[2,20]>` and if the second int difference is <2 I sum the first one output something like `<a> <[3,10]>` by adding the first int and keeping the lower of the second. When the next entry comes `<a> <[1,20]>` since |10-20| >2 I add the tuple to the list and output `<a> <[(3,10),(1,20)]>` then the next one gets me `<a> <[(3,10),(4,20)]>`
3. Finally I just map this to get key and the first value of the tuple

Hope this makes sense. I find it kind of inefficient since the lists must fit in memory and in the first case for each key with n initial values reducing is O(n^2).

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how you went from that input to that output?

Comment: Ok, please look at the edit.

Comment: Examples are at the top of the question? <key> <value>

Comment: Yes I see. What will happen if `<c> <1, 2> <c> <3, 4> <d> <5, 6> <d> <7, 8> <d> <9, 10>`

Comment: you would get the same output as the input, just without the second element of the value tuple